# How to identify whether the .jks is a keystore or a truststore?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

I have a .jks file. How can I identify whether it is a Keystore or a trust store?

Comment: A *truststore* contains certificates that you already trust to authenticate your peers. A *keystore* contains private keys that you will use to sign (and in some cases encrypt) data that will be sent to your peer. As the answer below notes, a single file may serve both purposes though I don't think that's typical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much of a difference, you can theoretically use one store for both purposes; Not that it's recommended though..

However, if you use Java Keytool to `-list` the contents of your stores, a Keystore should contain mainly `PrivateKeyEntry`s and a Truststore should contain mainly `trustedCertEntry`s

**KeyStore:**

```
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
<alias-1>, MMM dd, yyyy, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
<alias-2>, MMM dd, yyyy, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

**TrustStore:**

```
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
<alias-1>, MMM dd, yyyy, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
<alias-2>, MMM dd, yyyy, trustedCertEntry,
```